# Codeigniter remove index.php while working on virtual host on xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My previous folder tree was (with portable xampp): (for example working on D: drive root)

```
/xampp/htdocs/application
/xampp/htdocs/system
/xampp/htdocs/themes
/xampp/htdocs/index.php etc..
```

Now I am trying to shift into a structure which I can work with multiple projects so new tree:

```
/xampp/htdocs
/web_projects/project-name/codeigniter/application
/web_projects/project-name/codeigniter/system
/web_projects/project-name/htdocs/themes
/web_projects/project-name/htdocs/index.php
```

My **htaccess** file in htdocs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

# if Serves works on Linux OS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

# if Server works on Windows OS
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# if Serves works on Linux OS
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|plugins|system|themes|library|files) index.php/$1 [L]

# if Server works on Windows OS
# RewriteRule ^(application|modules|plugins|system|themes|library|files) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And **httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/web_projects"
    ServerName welcome.localhost
    <Directory "/web_projects">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/web_projects/test/htdocs"
    ServerName test.localhost
    <Directory "/web_projects/test/htdocs">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally **etc/host**:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 welcome.localhost
127.0.0.1 test.localhost
127.0.0.1 vstart # Alias for test
```

All virtual hosts are working, i.e. **http://vstart:8080/** is working but codeigniter not operates without index.php in address line, so routes are not working in accordance.

My **config/config.php** file is:

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

This set was working smoothly in my previous folder tree now is not working. I digged internet to find a solution with failure.

Any outer eyes to catch where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is you htaccess file in every "root" - you'll need three copies, once in each virtual server root directory.

Comment: @Robbie, of course, each htdocs has its own htaccess file, which are exactly same to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

All I need to do is add "AllowOverride All" to respected vhost.

Hope helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

New projects should be place inside the folder of "**htdocs**"

example:

xampp/htdocs/**new_project1**/index.htm

xampp/htdocs/**new_project1**/css

xampp/htdocs/**new_project1**/images

xampp/htdocs/**new_project2**/index.htm

xampp/htdocs/**new_project2**/css

xampp/htdocs/**new_project2**/images

Comment: yes but i'm trying to give you an idea on more simple deployment of your project by gibing this answer... that may also answers your problem why your program is nor running.

Comment: it is a common application to move codeigniter application folder out of doc root. Also the reason of not running is not the architect, is htacess. check my answer please.